# Prove $(A^c)^c = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Hey guys I know this is a super easy example but, this is my first day doing this stuff and i really need to get the basics down. Is this how to go about proving $(A^c)^c = A$

$$
\begin{align}
(A^c)^c & = (x\notin A)^c \\[6pt]
        & = \operatorname{NOT}(x\notin A) \\[6pt]
        & = A
\end{align}
$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Essentially, this boils down to cancelling two "not"s.  NOT NOT ($x \in A$) means $x \in A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention the basics, just get down to the bare definitions:

1. $X=Y$ if and only if $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$, which means that for every $x\in X$, $x\in Y$; and for every $y\in Y$, $y\in X$.
2. $x\in X^c$ if and only if $x\notin X$, that is to say it is false that $x\in X$.

---

Let $a\in A$, then $a\notin A^c$, therefore $a$ is not in $A^c$. So it follows that $a\in (A^c)^c$. So we have that $A\subseteq(A^c)^c$.

I will leave you to prove the other inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea, but don't use the $=$ sign when chasing an element.

I'll show you what I mean, and note that you can unpack it from the outside in. $$x\in (A^c)^c \iff x \notin (A^c) \iff \lnot (x \notin A) \iff \lnot(\lnot (x \in A)) \iff x \in A$$

Note the bidirectional implications $(\iff)$: each chain of implications, from left to right and from right to left, hold.

Since we've shown that $x \in (A^c)^c \iff x \in A$, it follows that set equality holds, i.e., $(A^c)^c = A$.